# What function could describe this GIF animation?

Tags: functions, matlab, parametric

I found this image on [Beautiful Mathematical GIFs Will Mesmerize You](http://www.iflscience.com/physics/beautiful-mathematical-gifs-will-mesmerize-you) and this GIF really caught my attention. From what I see, it's a 2D circle morphing into the 3D sphere. What function could describe this GIF animation? All comments are appreciated.

```
z < 0 -> red
z > 0 -> green
z = 0 -> blue
```

[image]

Comment: I'm really not sure if math.SE is the right place for this kind of questions. Pardon me if the question does not belong here and I will delete it.

Comment: Imagine a sphere and a "meridian" circle that connects two poles of the sphere. Now imagine that upper half of sphere is rotated clockwise, and other half -- counterclockwise. Also imagine that the amount of rotation depends on "latitude". Now the choice of concrete functions is up to you :)

Comment: To guess its parametrization ? arclength increases and decreases like some $ L\, sin^2 (\omega t) $ function of time parameter.

Comment: Original source: Bees & Bombs – [twisting circle](http://beesandbombs.tumblr.com/post/94454157654/twisting-circle) ([processing source code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/72d56637b43d11658e03)). Via [twitter](https://twitter.com/beesandbombs/status/498904611332554752).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a pretty direct translation to Mathematica of the processing code pointed out by horchler.  It's littered with spherical coordinates and I've placed the path on a sphere so that we can clearly see its 3D origin.

```
pics = Table[
   tw = 0.5 (1 - Cos[2 Pi*t]);
   tw = 3 Pi (0.5*tw + 1.5*tw*tw - tw*tw*tw);
   n = 720;
   r = 220;
   pts = Table[
     th = 2 Pi*i/n;
     ph = tw*Cos[th];
     x = r*Cos[th];
     y = r*Sin[th] Cos[ph];
     z = r*Sin[th]*Sin[ph];
     xx = x*Cos[Pi*t] - z*Sin[Pi*t];
     zz = -x*Sin[Pi*t] - z*Cos[Pi*t];
     {xx, y, zz},
     {i, 0, n - 1}];
   Rasterize[
    Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.2], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r]}, Tube[pts]},
     ViewPoint -> {1, 0, 10},
     ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0}, Boxed -> False], RasterSize -> 800, 
    ImageSize -> 400],
   {t, 0, 1, 0.02}];
ListAnimate[pics]
```

[image]

---

Here's my original answer that I obtained by just looking at the image.

We can get something like the middle phase as follows.  First, define $r_1$ and $r_2$ by
$$
\begin{align}
r_1(t) &= \sqrt[3]{|\cos(t/m)|} \\
r_2(t) &= \sqrt{|\cos((t-m\pi)/n)},
\end{align}
$$
where $m=3$ and $n=9$.  Then,
$$
p(t) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{cc}
    r_1(t) \, \langle \cos(t), \text{sgn}(r_1(t)) \sin(t) \rangle & 0 \leq t \leq m\pi \\
    r_2(t) \, \langle \cos((t-(m-1)\pi)), -\text{sgn}(r_2(t)) \sin((t-(m-1)\pi)) \rangle & m\pi < t \leq (m+n)\pi.
  \end{array}
\right.
$$
We can plot it in Mathematica:

```
{m, n} = {3, 9};
p[t_] := Piecewise[{
 {CubeRoot[Abs[Cos[t/m]]] {Cos[t], Sign[Cos[t/m]] Sin[t]}, 0<=t<=m*Pi},
 {Sqrt[Abs[Cos[(t - m*Pi)/n]]]*
   {Cos[(t-(m-1)*Pi)], -Sign[Cos[(t-m*Pi)/n]]*Sin[(t-(m-1)*Pi)]},
  m*Pi <= t <= (m + n) Pi}
}];
ParametricPlot[p[t], {t, 0, (m + n)*Pi}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Darker[ColorData["GrayYellowTones"][Sin[Pi #3]]] &),
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.8], Thickness[0.015]],
 Exclusions -> None, Axes -> None]
```

[image]

I can't quite seem to get the animation, though.

Answer (score 3):

The source code shows it: in spherical coordinates, $\phi=t_w\cos(\theta)$ where $t_w$ changes periodically over time between $0$ and $1$ (as a third degree polynomial of the cosine). The "sphere" also rotates uniformly and is displayed with perspective.

Comment: @Henry: quite right.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{cases}
x=\sin(t)\cos(\lambda t) \\
y=\cos(t)\cos(\lambda t) \\
z=\sin(\lambda t) \\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Note that this is a closed sperical curve.