# What is the mathematics behind the two animations?

Tags: computational-geometry, spherical-geometry

I found two animated GIFs from a designer's website, which looks very impressive:

[image]
[image]

My questions are:

what is the mathematics behind them? How to obtain the mathematical formulas and equations of the curve/surface?

The mesh in the left is different from normal rectangular ones; The curve in the right should be ones on a spherical surface. And both the two were said to be created via *Processing 2* software.

Comment: It's probably best to ask the creator of the animations.

Comment: The math of the one on the right has actually been discussed on here in the last half year or so.

Comment: thank you for comments and suggestions! @turkeyhundt do you have a link to the post?

Comment: The math of the left is probably just the wave equation solved and being animated on an hexagonal grid.

Comment: You can try searching for "animation".  This is on the first page of results, but can't remember if it's the one i saw.   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1149537/what-function-could-describe-this-gif-animation

Comment: thank you very much!  very useful!